# Conditionally skipping a variable assignment in a terraform module

Tags: terraform, terraform-modules, terraform-aws-modules

I'm currently using the terraform-aws-eks module and wanted to setup a managed node group in an existing cluster. However, I only want this node group to appear in our dev environment (but still want the cluster to remain unchanged). Is there a way to skip a variable assignment conditionally for a module? I tried the below approach but get an error if `var.deploy_managed_node_group = false`. Terraform version 0.14.11.

```
module "eks" {
  source = "./modules/eks-17.24.0"

  cluster_enabled_log_types = var.cluster_enabled_log_types
  cluster_name              = local.eks_cluster_name
  cluster_version           = local.eks_version
  iam_path                  = "/eks/"
  manage_aws_auth           = true
  map_users                 = local.eks_users
  map_roles                 = local.eks_roles
  subnets                   = module.eks_vpc.private_subnets

  vpc_id        = module.eks_vpc.vpc_id
  worker_groups = local.worker_groups

  node_groups = var.deploy_managed_node_group ? local.node_groups : null

}
```

```
Error: Iteration over null value
```

node_groups variable from module:

```
variable "node_groups" {
  description = "Map of map of node groups to create. See `node_groups` module's documentation for more details"
  type        = any
  default     = {}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using types in Terraform such as `set`, `list`, or `map`, the omitted value should be "empty" instead of `null` if the value is utilized for iteration instead of an argument. Therefore:

```
node_groups = var.deploy_managed_node_group ? local.node_groups : {}
```

would be the ideal ternary here as the falsey value returned by the conditional is an empty `map` constructor.

Comment: Marking as answer even though it didn't ultimately solve the problem turns out I would have to alter the variable type of the module to get this to work and was too much of a hassle. So I instead just set a conditional for the module resources as a workaround.